# Build and composite overlay image in external SVG filters file

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to rebuild [this yellowing effect](https://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-trendy-retro-photo-effect-purely-with-css) with SVG filters only so it could be applied to any image from an external filter file with `filter: url('filters.svg#yellowing')`.

So far I have managed to rebuild create the shapes which have to be used as an overlay to the SourceGraphic:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="400" height="300" viewBox="0 0 400 300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style><![CDATA[
    rect {
      mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    }
  ]]></style>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="yellowing-fill" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(255, 145, 0)" stop-opacity="0.2" />
      <stop offset="60%" stop-color="rgba(255, 230, 48)" stop-opacity="0.2" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="light-leak-fill" gradientTransform="rotate(-15, 1, 1)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0.5" />
      <stop offset="45%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0" />
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="inner-glow">
      <feFlood flood-color="black" />
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out" />
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="30" result="Blur" />
      <feBlend in2="Blur" />
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#light-leak-fill)" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#yellowing-fill)" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" filter="url(#inner-glow)" />
</svg>
```

But now I'm struggling converting this into a filter, I've tried the following (simplified):

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="yellowing">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="yellowing-fill" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(255, 145, 0)" stop-opacity="0.2" />
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="rgba(255, 230, 48)" stop-opacity="0.2" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="light-leak-fill" gradientTransform="rotate(-15, 1, 1)">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0.5" />
        <stop offset="45%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0" />
      </linearGradient>
      <filter id="inset-shadow-fill">
        <feFlood flood-color="black" />
        <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out" />
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="30" result="Blur" />
        <feBlend in2="Blur" />
        <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      </filter>
      <rect id="light-leak" fill="url(#light-leak-fill)" />
      <rect id="yellowing" fill="url(#yellowing-fill)" />
      <rect id="inset-shadow" fill="white" filter="url(#inset-shadow-fill)" />
    </defs>
    <feImage href="#light-leak" result="LightLeak" />
    <feImage href="#yellowing" result="Yellowing" />
    <feImage href="#inset-shadow" result="InsetShadow" />
    <feBlend in="LightLeak" in2="Yellowing" result="Blend1" mode="multiply" />
    <feBlend in="Blend1" in2="InsetShadow" result="Blend2" mode="multiply" />
    <feComposite in="Blend2" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

There must be several problems with this approach, most obviously, it appears wrong not to have any sizes declared anywhere.

Would it be better to put the above SVG image in a separate file e.g. `yellowing_overlay.svg` and then write a filter to composite it over the SourceGraphic in `filters.svg#yellowing` (by use of `feImage`) or is there a way to build the overlay in the filters file itself?

---

**UPDATE**

Having the yellowing overlay in a separate `yellowing_overlay.svg` and then using a filter to merge it with `SourceGraphic` seems more promising, however, it also doesn't work.

Since Stack Overflow does not yet support non-raster-image file uploads, I've created a gist with two files:

- `yellowing_overlay.svg` [gist](https://gist.github.com/svoop/38aba6a0f11c1d7c51148e410fb636c8?short_path=31e17b4) as shown in the fiddle above.
- `filters.svg` [gist](https://gist.github.com/svoop/38aba6a0f11c1d7c51148e410fb636c8?short_path=31e17b4) with the actual blending.

As well as the following sample image to be yellowed:

[image: sample image]

Putting the pieces together:

```css
  .filter-yellowing {
    filter: url('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/svoop/38aba6a0f11c1d7c51148e410fb636c8/raw/9a9311dd25e10e75731b4acd98b3f6583e413b31/filters.svg#yellowing');
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLnN5.jpg" width="400" height="300" class="filter-yellowing">
```

Running it... nothing on Firefox (Mac), unfiltered source image on Chrome (Mac) and Safari (Mac). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have it generally right in concept, but you have to size your feImages explicitly and if you want Firefox support, you can't use fragment identifiers as inputs to feImage, you have to inline them as Data-URI's. Your gradients and rects should be defined outside the filter - only filter primitives are supported within a filter element. Also filters don't nest - if you put your rects and gradients above your filter element, all your primitives should be contained within a single filter element.

Comment: @MichaelMullany I see, seems I'm poking a cross browser wasp nest here. Maybe the simpler approach with an external `yellowing_overlay.svg` could do the trick? I've updated the question with a much simpler such filter, but – bummer – it does not work on any browser.

Comment: I think you're running into filter security measures. Generally speaking, you have to serve your filter from the same domain as the calling page.

Comment: @MichaelMullany Okay, that's hard to mimic here, but for development, I'm serving all with browser-sync on localhost, so the domains should match. Still, same behaviour: Nothing on FF and unfiltered image on Chrome/Safari.

Comment: Well it could be this Chrome bug - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212#c82. And I'm not certain of this, but I don't think localhost is considered a valid host for filter security. I would start off trying to get this to work from a filter embedded in the serving page with the image, filter and filter image all served from the same (normal) web domain. Then see if externalizing the filter to a separate file works. Then see if moving the filter to a separate domain works.  Then see if moving the source image to a separate domain works.

Comment: FWIW - Firefox 84 just redefined localhost as a secure origin - so this wasn't supposed to work before now.